# Connectiong to API with C# NetworkingClient

Tags: c#, .net, api

Can someone help me with following API connection with C#. Never done any API connections before so i am a little unsure how it work. This is for a universal windows application so it will be using c# and XMAL.

Is it possible to do the following PHP API call below using C#:

```
<?php
$uri = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/354/fixtures/?matchday=22';
$reqPrefs['http']['method'] = 'GET';
$reqPrefs['http']['header'] = 'X-Auth-Token: YOUR_TOKEN';
$stream_context = stream_context_create($reqPrefs);
$response = file_get_contents($uri, false, $stream_context);
$fixtures = json_decode($response);
?>
```

Basically all i need to know is if it is even possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post what you have done so far? Do you expect us to do the code for you?

Comment: no i dont want code i just wanted to know if it is possible. Sorry for the confusion in the question i will edit it.

Comment: Yes it's possible to call a web api with C# client.

Answer (score 1):

It can be something like this (result is as text but you can json too):

```
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/354/fixtures/?matchday=22");
request.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", "Basic YTph");
request.ContentType = "text/html";
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string ResultAsText = stream.ReadToEnd().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my favorite example of calling a WEB API: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

It shows how to use `HttpClient`, uses `async / await` and introduces Formatters.